# convert req.connection.remoteAddress to not include :ffff

Tags: node.js, express

I have node js application where I am capturing IP address using the following piece of code:

```
  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||  
  req.connection.remoteAddress ||
```

Here, req.connection.remoteAddress appends ::ffff: before the actual IP.
Is there a standard way to have only the IP returned without the ::ffff: before other than stripping it? Is there some API or something to invoke to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions to capture only what is after the `::ffff:`:

```js
var reg = /([^f:]+)/;
var str = '::ffff:127.0.0.1';
    
alert(reg.exec(str)[0]);
```

Comment: my question is, is there any other standard way of converting the IPAddress or stripping/regex the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ipaddr.js`](https://github.com/whitequark/ipaddr.js) for that:

```
const ipaddr = require('ipaddr.js');

let mappedAddr = '::ffff:127.0.0.1';
let ipv4Addr   = ipaddr.process(mappedAddr).toString(); // -> 127.0.0.1
```